# If statements with dates in R: determine if columns fall in between an interval

Tags: r

Very new to StackOverflow so I apologize if this is not in the correct format!

d$a shows when a student enrolls.  d$b shows if a student withdrew, if they have NA for this column, they are still enrolled.  I want to create a new column (fcount) in my dataframe (d) if a student is enrolled 20 or more days during the interval of 8/15/2017 to 11/30/2017.  If they are, fcount would read TRUE.  If not, fcount would read FALSE.  I'm having trouble putting the algorithms into an ifelse formula.

Here is how you decide true or false for d$fcount:

-If d$a <= 11/10/2017 & d$b = na, then d$fcount = TRUE

-If d$a > 11/10/2017, then d$fcount = FALSE

-If d$a <= 11/10/2017, then d$b = NA OR d$b has to be 20 days greater than d$a, d$fcount = TRUE

-If d$b < 9/3/2017, then d$fcount = FALSE

`lastname <- c('King', 'Heathcoat', 'White', 'Clark', 'Cobbs', 'Badgette')
a <- c('8/14/2017', '8/14/2017', '8/21/2017','8/21/2017', '11/13/2017', '11/13/2017')
b <- c('1/30/18', NA, '9/28/2017','8/29/2017', NA, '3/1/2018')

d <- data.frame(lastname, a, b)`

My desired output would look like this: 
[Desired Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KeEfq.png)

Answer (score 1):

I shortened the variable names to reduce typing and removed the quotation marks from the `NA` so that the values would be correctly marked as missing. After converting the date strings to R's `Date` class, you can do arithmetic on the dates to check the number of days enrolled.

```
library(lubridate)

lastname <- c('King', 'Heathcoat', 'White', 'Clark', 'Cobbs')
a <- c('8/14/2017', '8/14/2017', '8/21/2017','8/21/2017', '11/13/2017')
b <- c('1/30/18', NA, '9/28/2017','8/29/2017', NA)

d <- data.frame(lastname, a, b)

# Convert date columns to Date class
d$a = mdy(d$a)
d$b = mdy(d$b)  

d$fcount = ifelse(is.na(d$b), d$a <= mdy("11/30/2017") - 20, d$b - d$a >= 20)
```

> ```
>    lastname          a          b fcount
> 1      King 2017-08-14 2018-01-30   TRUE
> 2 Heathcoat 2017-08-14       <NA>   TRUE
> 3     White 2017-08-21 2017-09-28   TRUE
> 4     Clark 2017-08-21 2017-08-29  FALSE
> 5     Cobbs 2017-11-13       <NA>  FALSE
> ```

Comment: I tried using that code, but it doesn't seem to be working throughout my entire dataframe.  For example, I have a student lastname=Badgette, a=2017/11/13, b=2018/3/1.  This student should have fcount=false because he was only enrolled 17 days during that time frame.  I tried changing the 11/30/2017 to 11/10/2017 (this would be the cut off date for d$a.

Comment: So you have dates that span more than one year and different cutoff dates for different terms? Please post a data sample that covers the range of possible cases in your real data and let us know how the cutoff dates are determined.

Comment: I edited the post to include Badgette and a little bit more of an explanation.  I apologize for being so vague.  I really appreciate all of your help!